# Extreme values of an inverse trigonometric expression

Tags: derivatives

I have to show that $\arcsin \frac{2x}{x^2+1}+2\arctan (x)=\pi$ when x is equal or bigger than 1 and $\arcsin \frac{2x}{x^2+1}+2\arctan(x)=-\pi$ when $x$ is smaller than $1$, $x$ being a real number from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ .

I have to use Lagrange's theorem for this but I do not really know how. I tried to calculate the derivative of that $f(x)$, and I got that it is:

$$\frac{2}{x^2+1}\left(1-\frac{x^2-1}{|x^2-1|}\right)$$

about which I said that it needs to be $0$. Is it correct?

Comment: I suspect your problem statement leaves out some conditions on $x$.  Do you intend to require $x \ge 0$?

Comment: No. It is for x real number

Comment: If $0 < x < 1$ both functions yield positive values so the sum can't be negative. Do you mean when $x$ is smaller than $-1$?

Comment: I do not know maybe the problem is wrong.

Comment: I think Umberto's suggestion is apt (that the second portion should be "when $x$ is smaller than $-1$").  Note that your function $f(x)$ is an odd function (as the sum of two odd functions), and that your expression for the derivative is zero when $|x| \gt 1$.  Also $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.

$$\left(\arcsin\frac{2x}{x^2+1}+2\arctan x\right)'=\frac{2(x^2+1)-2x\cdot2x}{(x^2+1)^2}\frac2{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{4x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}}}+\frac1{x^2+1}\\
=2\frac{1-x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}\dfrac{x^2+1}{|x^2-1|}+\frac2{x^2+1}=2\frac{\text{sgn}(1-x^2)+1}{x^2+1}.$$

For $|x|\ge1$, this is $0$ and the function is constant in the two regions.

Then

$$\arcsin\frac{2(\pm1)}{(\pm1)^2+1}+2\arctan(\pm1)=\pm\pi.$$